# Next with vercel deployment - How to achieve a reusable CORS middleware on api?

Tags: typescript, express, next.js, cors, vercel

I've been playing around trying to avoid a CORS error with my next app which is deployed on vercel. The only way I managed to do this was by manually setting the headers on each api request... eg:

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  )

  // Handle pre-flight requests
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end()
    return
  }

  let houses: House[] = []

  try {
    await client.connect()
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')

    const db = client.db('vroom')
    const housesCollection = db.collection('houses')

    houses = (await housesCollection.find().toArray()).map((house) => ({
      house: house.house,
      price: house.price,
      timestamp: house.timestamp,
      developer: house.developer,
    }))

    console.log('Retrieved houses:', houses)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error connecting to MongoDB: ${error}`)
  } finally {
    await client.close()
  }

  res.json({ houses })
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result either via the middleware.ts file, or through some sort of wrapper code?

I hope this makes sense but please ask for any clarification if not!

Thanks

I tried the above but have to enter some text here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do the next best thing and create a wrapper for my apis facing that cors error:

here's a utils/middlware.ts file:

```
import { NextApiHandler, NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import Cors from 'cors'

const corsMiddleware = Cors({
  methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD'],
})

const runMiddleware = (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
  fn: Function
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn(req, res, (result: any) => {
      if (result instanceof Error) {
        return reject(result)
      }

      return resolve(result)
    })
  })
}

export const withCors =
  (handler: NextApiHandler) =>
  async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    await runMiddleware(req, res, corsMiddleware)

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.status(200).end()
      return
    }

    return handler(req, res)
  }
```

Which can then be used like so:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { connectToDB, paginateCollection, withCors } from '@/utils'

export type House = {
  house: string
  price: string
  timestamp: string
  developer: string
}

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page as string) || 1
  const perPage = 10

  let houses: House[] = []
  let totalPages = 1

  try {
    const db = await connectToDB()

    const housesCollection = db.collection('foo')

    const { items, totalPages: pages } = await paginateCollection(
      housesCollection,
      page,
      perPage
    )
    totalPages = pages

    houses = items.map((house) => ({
      house: house.house,
      price: house.price,
      timestamp: house.timestamp,
      developer: house.developer,
    }))
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error connecting to MongoDB: ${error}`)
  }

  res.json({ houses, totalPages })
}

export default withCors(handler)
```

Hope that helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Nextjs-Cors` or use your `Own Code` as a middleware (see below).

Create a `middleware.ts (or .js)` file at the same level as your pages (in the `root` or `src` directory)

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import NextCors from 'nextjs-cors';

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const res = NextResponse.next()
 // Run the cors middleware
   await NextCors(req, res, {
      // Options
      methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
      origin: '*',
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
   });
  return res
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-cors

```
# Using npm
npm install --save nextjs-cors@latest

# Using yarn
yarn add nextjs-cors@latest

# Using pnpm
pnpm add nextjs-cors@latest
```

---

## Using Your Own Code (without dependancies)

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const res = NextResponse.next()
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  )

  // Handle pre-flight requests
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return new NextResponse('ok',{status:200})

  }

  return res
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort but unfortunately I was having lots of type errors, even with tweaks. I managed to get something working which I'll share below, it's not perfect since I'm sure it should be possible to use next's middleware.ts file to do this on all api routes - but it works for now.